# How can I insert a lightning bolt symbol for Google's AMP page format?

Tags: html, mobile, accelerated-mobile-page

If you visit [the Accelerated Mobile Pages HTML specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#ampd), you will see that the `<html>` tag has a lightning bolt before the closing bracket:

`<html ⚡>`

Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use or configure to insert this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the docs said you could just use `<html amp>`, I'm assuming you asked this question cause you'd rather use the symbol. In that case, the easiest route would be to highlight and copy the symbol and then paste it into your code. The other option I know of is to use an [Alt Code](http://www.alt-codes.net/how_to_use_alt_codes/) to type the symbol into your code. The alt code for the lightning symbol is Alt + 26A1 Hold alt and type the code into the number pad on your keyboard and it *should* work.

Comment: for me it print ☺in windows - visual stuido

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is/was no easy way to type alt codes on Mac (if i hold option and type 26A1 I get this: `™ˆ̄¡`.

It seems MacOS has a nice emoji shortcut (Ctrl + Cmd + Space) in which you can find and select the lightning bolt. https://support.apple.com/en-gw/ht201586

Works for me in a text editor.

Comment: From my understanding, you have to have a numpad (rather than the top numerical keys) for that code to work.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Windows 10, press `win-.` (that is, the windows key and the period key) to open the emoji picker. Then, start typing `lightning bolt` and choose the ⚡ by pressing enter. (Technically, the symbol is called `high voltage` so if you type `high v` and press enter the ⚡ emoji should appear)

Answer (score 1):

The 26A1 is an Alt + X code. To use only an ALT key it is ALT + 9889.